# WinUI notifications: COM exception is raised when instanciating instance of "AppNotification"

Tags: notifications, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I wanted to include notifications in my existing WinUI 3 application which uses Windows App SDK 1.1.4 and .NET 6 (The application does not and shall not use packaging / MSIX).

In order to achieve this, I tried to extract some code of an example application that I created with the "Template studio for WinUI" project template (assistant), see https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/ (The sample application also works with the 'unpackaged' deployment model).

The code which I extracted from the example application looks like this (the relevant parts should be the methods 'Initialize' and 'Show'):

```
public class AppNotificationService : IAppNotificationService
{
    public AppNotificationService()
    {

    }

    ~AppNotificationService()
    {
        Unregister();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        AppNotificationManager.Default.NotificationInvoked += OnNotificationInvoked;

        AppNotificationManager.Default.Register();
    }

    public void OnNotificationInvoked(AppNotificationManager sender, AppNotificationActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Handle notification invocations when your app is already running.

        //// // Navigate to a specific page based on the notification arguments.
        //// if (ParseArguments(args.Argument)["action"] == "Settings")
        //// {
        ////    App.MainWindow.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        ////    {
        ////        _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SettingsViewModel).FullName!);
        ////    });
        //// }

        App.MainWindow.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        {
            App.MainWindow.ShowMessageDialogAsync("TODO: Handle notification invocations when your app is already running.", "Notification Invoked");

            App.MainWindow.BringToFront();
        });
    }

    // EXCEPTION IN THIS METHOD
    public bool Show(string payload)
    {
        var appNotification = new AppNotification(payload); // COM EXCEPTION HERE

        AppNotificationManager.Default.Show(appNotification);

        return appNotification.Id != 0;
    }

    public NameValueCollection ParseArguments(string arguments)
    {
        return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(arguments);
    }

    public void Unregister()
    {
        AppNotificationManager.Default.Unregister();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code contains a method "Show" that has a string for the payload that represents the notification message. In addition there is a "Initialize" method that the example code calls upon application startup.

In order to call the "Show" method of the code above, I created some small event handler in my application that gets called when I click a button:

```
    private void CreateNotification_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppNotificationService notificationService = new AppNotificationService();
        notificationService.Initialize();

        string notificationContent = "test";
        notificationService.Show(notificationContent);
    }
```

However, the call to "notificationService.Show(notificationContent);" always causes a `ComException` "0xC00CE556" that is raised when the code tries to instanciate the `AppNotification` instance see here:

[image]

I do not know what I am missing here. It seems that the template studio application does something additional to get the notification working, that I am currently not doing in my code. But I have no idea what that is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at [Winui3 notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/) which lists some steps in order to send notification. [The notification samples](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Notifications) work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the link. By investigating the examples there, I found out, that my problem was related to the string I used as notification content. This must not be an arbitrary string (like "test"), but an xml string that has a specific format which is needed for "toast" messages. I will write an answer here in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your COM Exception but these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/app-notifications-quickstart?tabs=cs) worked.

1. Create a simple WinUI 3 app project.
2. Bring **AppNotificationService.cs** and **IAppNotificationService.cs** from a **TemplateStudio** project with app notifications.
3. Open **Package.appxmanifest** using a text editor (VSCode).
4. Add these namespaces:

```xml
<Package
  xmlns:com="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/com/windows10"
  xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10">

</Package>
```

5. Declare these **Extensions** inside **Applications**:

```xml
<Applications>
  <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
    <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="WinUI3BlankAppProjectTemplate" Description="WinUI3BlankAppProjectTemplate" BackgroundColor="transparent" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png">
      <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
      <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    </uap:VisualElements>

    <Extensions>
      <!--Specify which CLSID to activate when notification is clicked-->
      <desktop:Extension Category="windows.toastNotificationActivation">
        <desktop:ToastNotificationActivation ToastActivatorCLSID="12345678-9ABC-DEFG-HIJK-LMNOPQRSTUVW" />
      </desktop:Extension>

      <!--Register COM CLSID-->
      <com:Extension Category="windows.comServer">
        <com:ComServer>
          <com:ExeServer Executable="AppNotifications.exe" Arguments="----AppNotificationActivated:" DisplayName="Toast activator">
            <com:Class Id="12345678-9ABC-DEFG-HIJK-LMNOPQRSTUVW" DisplayName="Toast activator" />
          </com:ExeServer>
        </com:ComServer>
      </com:Extension>
    </Extensions>

  </Application>
</Applications>
```

6. Replace `Executable="AppNotifications.exe"` with your app name.
7. Create a GUID from [Tools]-[Create GUID] in VisualStudio menu.
8. Replace the two GUIDs in the **Extensions** with the GUID you created.
9. Save the Package.appxmanifest file and reopen and rebuild the solution.
10. Call the `Show` method passing a valid payload. For example:

```cs
var xmlPayload =
@"
<toast launch=""action=ToastClick"">
  <visual>
    <binding template=""ToastGeneric"">
      <text>App Notification</text>
      <text></text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action content=""Settings"" arguments=""action=Settings""/>
  </actions>
</toast>
";
appNotificationService.Show(xmlPayload);
```

**UPDATE**

For un-packaged(non-packaged) apps you get a COM Exception if you don't call the `Initialize()` method. So, the step 10. should be something like this:

10. Call `Initialize` then `Show` method passing a valid payload. For example:

```cs
AppNotificationService appNotificationService = new();
appNotificationService.Initialize();
var xmlPayload =
@"
<toast launch=""action=ToastClick"">
  <visual>
    <binding template=""ToastGeneric"">
      <text>App Notification</text>
      <text></text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action content=""Settings"" arguments=""action=Settings""/>
  </actions>
</toast>
";
appNotificationService.Show(xmlPayload);
```

Comment: Does this work for unpackaged applications?  I have an unpackged application (will update the question accordingly). Package.appxmanifest is for packaged applications only, correct?

Comment: Thank you for your time. The ComException occurs when the xmlPayload string does not have the correct format or does not represent xml, see the answer I posted.

Comment: It worked for me by calling the ``Initialize`` method. Even though the docs say skip it...

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was in my case.

I turned out, that **the problem was related to the string I used as notification content**. This must not be an arbitrary string (like *`"test"`* in the example I used in the question), but an xml string that has a specific format which is needed to represent a "toast" message.

This xml string for the toast message can contain specific elements for text, images and buttons that may appear in the message.

Simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>Some text</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

This article shows an example of the possible syntax of this xml string:

[Quickstart: App notifications in the Windows App SDK - 4 Display an app notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/app-notifications-quickstart?tabs=cs#step-4-display-an-app-notification)

There are also classes and helpers for the construction of the xml string that you can use by installing the *"CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications"*
Nuget package:

[ToastContent class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=builder-syntax)

[ToastContentBuilder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.notifications.toastcontentbuilder.-ctor?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications.ToastContentBuilder.%2523ctor)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0)

**Example code**

Basically, all you need to do to create a toast notification is this:

```
private void CreateNotification_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Version 1: Directly define the xmlPayload string:
    // string xmlPayload = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><toast><visual><binding template=""ToastGeneric""><text>Some text</text></binding></visual></toast>";


    // Version 2: Create the the xmlPayload string using the ToastContentBuilder
    // ToastContentBuilder comes with the "CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications" Nuget package
    ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContentBuilder()
        .AddText("Some text")
        .GetToastContent();

    string xmlPayload = toastContent.GetContent();


    var toast = new AppNotification(xmlPayload);
    AppNotificationManager.Default.Show(toast);
}
```

In the example code, I have two versions on how to create the xml string that represents the toast message. You can create the xml yourself or use the [ToastContentBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.notifications.toastcontentbuilder.gettoastcontent?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) class from the *"CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications"* Nuget package.

**Personal opinion**

I know that StackOverflow does no focus on personal opinions. However, I would like to express that I am quite disappointed to see that a code like

```
new AppNotification("test");
```

raises an `ComException` lacking any useful information instead of an meaningful exception that contains some hint for the developer complaining about the incorrect format of the provided xml string.

Comment: It's difficult to report what's the problem about the payload string but I also think It's necessary to report the problem about the payload string. By the way, [AppNotification constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.appnotifications.appnotification.-ctor?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) states that *The notification payload representation in xml*.

Comment: Yes, could have taken a look into that documentation. This doc for the 'AppNotification' constructor could indicate at least a hint what the xml is, but the way. However the usual behavior for the implementation would be to throw a "ArgumentException" if an invalid value is provided. It could also have to do with the way certain exceptions are routed in the Windows App SDK, but that I do not know.